# Why does the pseudo element overlays parent?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to move the pseudo `::after` element **below** the `parent` div. But it doesnt work too well. How to move the green box under blue?

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.parent::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  background: green;
  content: '';
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" />
```

Comment: you don't need extra wrapper, remove z-index from the parent element and use a negative z-index on the pseudo element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause you have `position: relative` on `.parent`. You can add a `.container` and move `position: relative` to it.

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.parent::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  background: green;
  content: '';
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent" />
</div>
```